# How to get the data value in Jstree

Tags: java, javascript, html, json, jquery-ui

I tried to get the data for the selected node in jstree. 
I can able to get the ID using data.rslt.obj.attr('id')
But if i want to retrieve the email id of user101,
How to get the data values according to selected node?
I tried data.rslt.obj.attr('data'), but not able to achieve, please advise.

```
{
   "state":"open",
   "data":"com",
   "attr":{
      "id":"test1",
   },
   "children":[
      {
         "state":"open",
         "attr":{
            "id":"testus1",
         },
         "data":{
            "title":"vls",
            "emailAddress":"vls@gmail.com"
         },
         "children":[
            {
               "state":"closed",
               "attr":{
                  "id":"testus2",
               },
               "data":{
                  "title":"vfg"
               },
               "children":[
                  null,
                  {
                     "state":"closed",
                     "attr":{
                        "id":"testus3",
                     },
                     "data":{
                        "title":"user19"
                     },
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "state":"closed",
                           "attr":{
                              "id":"user101",
                           },
                           "data":{
                              "title":"user101",
                              "emailAddress":"test1@csc.com"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "state":"closed",
                           "attr":{
                              "id":"testus11",
                           },
                           "data":{
                              "title":"testuser11",
                              "emailAddress":"test@csc.com"
                           },
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            null
         ]
      },
      null
   ]
}

Regards,
Prabkar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to store properties, you have to use 'metadata' attribute, which can take a string, array or object as value. I see that you are using 'data' for this. You should try using 'metadata' instead of 'data'.

Please note that you should still use the following statement to retrieve the property you set in metadata.

```
data.rslt.obj.attr('data')
```